# Баг перевода review -> последние отзывы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Ссылка review в верхем тулбаре переведена как "последние отзывы". Должна быть "проверки" или "очереди проверок":
 [image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Comment: Спасибо за замечание! Изменили на "очередь проверок".

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky♦, Я всё ещё вижу "последние отзывы".

Comment: @ModaL: Думаю, данные кешируются, и изменения видны не сразу.

Comment: @ModaL Скорее всего, на сайте строки обновятся завтра.